# I was bitten by a kitten not even a month old, what should I do?

Tags: cats, safety, diseases, strays

I was bitten by not even a month old kitten which is a stray; this happened when I was trying to help it get to it's mom. The bite is not deep and is very shallow, it's like very small dots. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to pets, where do you live? Is rabies endemic where you live?

Comment: I am asking about rabies, but please don't panic, the chance that this little cat was rabid is extremely small, most probably you will be all right, I have been bitten and scratched to blood by stray cats quite a few times and nothing bad ever happened, I was fine.

Comment: However, regardless of anything, you should disinfect the wound as soon as you can with a disinfectant like ethyl or isopropyl alcohol from pharmacy or at least wash and clean the wound with clean water.

Comment: Contact your doctor.

Comment: You will be a catman. Extreme agility with good vision in low light.

Comment: @Kai Why? As a high-rep user you should know better than not to answer questions with throw-away comments like that with no explanation.

Comment: were you wearing a mitten? In Britain? Glad you've written

Comment: Maybe you rethink having a pet ,it a monthold kitten bite is a concern.

Comment: See a doctor. Then adopt the kitten.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I am not sure, but for me it sounds like this kitten is not a pet, but a homeless stray instead and the person asking only tried to help it find its mom, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: A good time to go update *all* your shots even if they are.

Comment: @lila "Look at me, I've done it several times and I'm fine" is not particularly [useful advice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anecdotal_evidence) when it comes to health.

Comment: @JBentley On the other hand, assuming that everything is fine untill proven otherwise is a very successful strategy. "Relax - it'll be fine" is a valid answer to this question, methinks.

Comment: @StianYttervik On the contrary, there are plenty of diseases which are treatable if caught early but fatal if ignored. [Rabies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabies#Treatment) being a great example. "Relax - it'll be fine" is the absolute worst strategy if Rabies is a possibility. The survival rate with treatment is 100% while the death rate after symptoms appear is close to 100%.

Comment: @JBentley Nah. The opportunity cost has to be applied to every similar situation. Always assuming the worst is a very dear price to pay, imho. I do agree with taking the rabies vaccine though, there is no downside to that. And this can be a reasonable reminder and motivation to do so. But I wouldn't stop assuming that everything was OK and it was - literally - just a scratch.

Comment: @StianYttervik That's not the point being made here. The person I responded to said "most probably you will be all right" and you'll notice I didn't disagree with that. The point is that whatever the situation (i.e. high odds or low odds), anecdotal evidence is close to useless and "I did it and I was fine" doesn't prove or disprove anything. You should weigh up the situation on its facts.

Answer (score 30):

First off, rule one for an animal bite (beyond the obvious first step of thoroughly cleaning it and properly bandaging it) is to contact your doctor ASAP, even if it seems innocuous. There are two reasons this is important:

- Bite wounds are almost always puncture wounds, and puncture wounds are notoriously difficult to clean properly. Because of this, even if cleaned and dressed promptly they still pose a non-negligible infection risk.
- There are all kinds of seemingly strange potential complications with animal bites, ranging from infections with pathogens you would not normally be exposed to (*Bartonella henselae* being a good example of this with cats) to stuff that sounds absolutely crazy at first unless you have a background in medicine or zoology (such as non-venomous snake bites running the risk of having splinters of the teeth left in the wound because of how fragile many snake’s teeth are).

Now, as far as risks here from a bite from a feral cat, the three big ones are (note, this is *not* a complete list, I am not a doctor or veterinarian, and you should still contact your doctor):

- Rabies: Risk varies based on what part of the world you are in. If you live in a region where rabies is uncommon, keep an eye on the cat for the next ten days, paying attention that it does not die or exhibit unwarranted aggression. Past that you are clear (note though that if it does die or exhibit unwarranted aggression, this is not a guarantee that you have rabies, just an indication that you should be treated as if you do). If you are living in a region where rabies is common, contact your doctor ASAP and begin treatment.
- Tetanus: Simply ensure your vaccinations for tetanus are up to date, and if not get them up to date and you should be fine. Tetanus vaccination is painful for a few days, but generally has no other complications, and is far preferable to actually contracting tetanus, and as long as you are properly vaccinated it’s not a serious risk.
- Cat Scratch Disease: More specifically, the aforementioned bacteria *Bartonella henselae*. Risk here is actually a bit higher than it would normally be because it’s a young cat. CSD is generally not serious unless it goes septic (which is rare) or you are already immunocompromised (if you do not know what that means, you almost certainly are not), though it is rather unpleasant. Symptoms typically show up within 3-14 days. If you develop a bump or blister near where you were bitten, and/or develop painfully swollen lymph nodes, see your doctor about it promptly.

Answer (score 9):

**It depends on where you live.**

If you are living in a western country, chances are rabies is almost completely eliminated. Disinfect the wound as soon as it happens. You will be fine.

To make certain that you are fine, you might want to follow these steps:

- Disinfect the wound.
- Watch out for the cat regularly for ten days.
- If it dies, gets into a bloody fight or shows unwarranted aggression, contact the doctor immediately.

You are clear after ten days.

However, **rabies is not your biggest concern, tetanus is**. Make sure that your vaccinations are upto date for tetanus. If not, get vaccinated as soon as possible. It is a painful vaccination, usually causes pain in the muscle it is administered to for a day but other than that it has no complications.

If you are living in a country where rabies occur frequently, contact a doctor ASAP. For additional information on rabies exposure and treatment please refer to the World Health Organisation's [Rabies Fact Sheet](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/rabies).

Comment: and,  just to get it out there,  the important thing with both of them but especially rabies,  is that you can't wait until you get sick.   You need to take action immediately, either to seriously rule out rabies or to start the injections.  Both cause truly miserable pain and suffering, and rabies is completely fatal - completely.

Comment: @MikeM There have been survivors of symptomatic rabies! ...specifically, 14. Ever. In the history of mankind...

Comment: @KRyan -- yup... not a good scene